ODBC Connection Error in Python Virtual Environment: `Login failed for user 'userx'` (SQL Server)
I'm facing an issue while trying to connect to my SQL Server database using pyodbc and SQLAlchemy in a Python virtual environment on my M1 Mac. The connection works perfectly in my global Python environment but fails in the virtual environment with the following error:

Error connecting to the database: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'userx'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Environment Details:

Global Environment:

Python: 3.11
pyodbc and SQLAlchemy installed globally via pip
Successful connection


Virtual Environment:

Python: 3.11 (same as global)
pyodbc and SQLAlchemy installed via pip
Connection fails with the login error



Debug Information:

Both environments list the same available ODBC drivers, including ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server.
The environment variables for the database connection are correctly loaded and verified.
The connection string appears correct and matches the format that works in the global environment.

Connection String:
import pyodbc
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Load environment variables
load_dotenv()

# Set connection variables
SQL_USER = os.getenv("SQL_USER")
SQL_PASS = os.getenv("SQL_PASS")
SQL_SERVER = os.getenv("SQL_SERVER")
SQL_PORT = os.getenv("SQL_PORT")
SQL_DATABASE = os.getenv("SQL_DATABASE")

# Define the connection string using the full path to the ODBC Driver
connection_string = (
    f"DRIVER={{{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}}};"
    f"SERVER={SQL_SERVER},{SQL_PORT};"
    f"DATABASE={SQL_DATABASE};"
    f"UID={SQL_USER};"
    f"PWD={SQL_PASS};"
    f"TDS_Version=8.0;"
)

# Test the connection
try:
    conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
    print("Connection successful!")
    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error connecting to the database: {e}")

Steps Taken:

Verified that the username and password are correct.
Ensured that the environment variables are correctly loaded in both environments.

Additional Information:

The same credentials and connection string work in the global environment.
The SQL Server logs do not provide additional insights beyond the generic login failure error.

Question:
What could be causing this discrepancy between the global and virtual environments, and how can I resolve the login failure issue in my virtual environment?

Does the password contain punctuation characters? Are they stored correctly in the environment variables? (i.e.: do they render correctly with you export in the virtual environment?) Some characters, like !, have special meaning in various shells (e.g.: ! for accessing bash history).

Do you yourself have admin access to the SQL Server to which these processes are connecting? Are you able to check the ERRORLOG file to see what information SQL Server reports around the error 18456 events? In particular you can take note of the reported State number and compare it against those listed at MSSQLSERVER_18456 to determine exactly why the login is failing.
